# How to filter PCAP for TLS "application data" packets?

Tags: tls, wireshark

I have a `pcap` file containing encrypted traffic.

I want to filter SSL packets that contain application data. Note that I do not want to decrypt the traffic, but just want to note the packets that have encrypted data. Initially, I was using [content type field (value = `23`)](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-5) in TLS record to filter out such traffic.

However, in the pcap file I observe packets with different content type such as `12`, `108`, `73` etc. I could not find what do they signify from the RFC.

Comment: There are no assigned ContentType's with these values according to [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-5). Could you provide the pcap so that one could have a closer look?

Comment: Here is the link for the pcap file: https://ufile.io/gb1ue

Comment: Also, here is a snippet of one the TLSRecord read using scapy_ssl: <SSL  records=[<TLSRecord  content_type=51 version=0x70c2 length=0x3c44 |<TLSCiphertext ...> Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've checked the provided pcap file and counted the used ContentType's in the SSL traffic:

```
$ tshark -O ssl -r youtube_song_wireshark.pcap tcp.port == 443 |\
grep 'Content Type' | sort | uniq -c
```

This gives me 64 x Alert(21), 86 x ChangeCipherSpec(20), 362 x Handshake(22), 2188 x ApplicationData(23). It does not give any of the ContentType's you've seen in your analysis.

In a comment you provide the following snippet of the results returned by your scapy based analysis:

```
<SSL records=[<TLSRecord content_type=51 version=0x70c2 length=0x3c44 |<TLSCiphertext ...>
```

Given that there is no SSL/TLS version 0x70c2 but that the version should be in the range of 0x0300 (SSL 3.0) to 0x0303 (TLS 1.2) I suspect that you parse data as SSL which are not SSL at all and that you get such a strange result then. There is several non-SSL traffic in the pcap you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using scapy_ssl to parse the data. I do check if a packet has SSL layer before looking for content type. I think it might be an issue with the scapy_ssl parsing. I will explore it further.